# safari not allowing a second window.print()

Tags: javascript, html, printing, safari

Hello I am running into a weird issue in Safari. I have a button and when clicked it prints the content of the html. My issue is that when calling on `window.print()` the first time it works great, however, on the second click it will display a popup stating:

> 'This webpage is trying to print. Do you want to print this webpage?'

If I click *Print* in this dialog nothing happens. Any ideas why this could be happening? Thank you in advance!

Javascript -

```
$scope.print = function() {
    var contents = document.getElementById("print-section").outerHTML;
    var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
    frame1.name = "frame3";
    frame1.style.position = "absolute";
    frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
    document.body.appendChild(frame1);

    var frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.document ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
    frameDoc.document.open();
    frameDoc.document.write('<html><head>'); // add some libraries for the new document
    frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
    frameDoc.document.write(contents);
    frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
    frameDoc.document.close();
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.frames["frame3"].focus();
        window.frames["frame3"].print();
        document.body.removeChild(frame1);
    }, 500);

    return false;
};
```

Html-

```
<div id="print-section">
   <div>Section to print<>
</div>
```

Comment: Same problem here, any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

As Matteo Conta correctly mentioned, the problem is that Safari's print confirmation dialog does not stop JS code execution flow to wait for printing.
Therefore, what we really want is to detect when exactly does a print action end in order to run a cleanup absolutely safely.

`setTimeout` solution is a good starting point but I wanted to tackle the problem more reliably and have come up with an event-based solution using `matchMedia` and `onfocus` to catch the exact moment when printing is finished (either cancelled or completed).

Below is the code that I've tested for this particular question (ES5, iframe printing).
Also, I've created [a Gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/capturetheflag/a588f4d5919efebf2eae315aeb9e2297) with a generic approach demonstrated. Hope it will be useful.

```
$scope.print = function () {
  var frame = appendFrame();

  // Safari
  if (!window.onafterprint) {
    // emulate onbeforeprint/onafterprint events
    var mediaQueryCallback = function (mql) {
      if (!mql.matches && frame) {
        document.body.removeChild(frame);
      }
    };
    var mediaQueryList = window.frames[frame.name].matchMedia('print');
    mediaQueryList.addListener(mediaQueryCallback);

    // the code below will trigger a cleanup in case a user hits Cancel button
    // in that Safari's new additional print confirmation dialog
    window.frames[frame.name].focus();
    window.frames[frame.name].onfocus = function () {
      return mediaQueryCallback(mediaQueryList);
    };
  }

  window.frames[frame.name].print();

  return false;
};
```

For brevity I've extracted the frame creation code into a trivial function (`appendFrame`) and omitted `setTimeout` call from the original question (after `frameDoc.document.close();` line).

```
var appendFrame = function () {
  var contents = document.getElementById("print-section").outerHTML;
  var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
  frame1.name = "frame3";
  frame1.style.position = "absolute";
  frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
  document.body.appendChild(frame1);

  var frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.document ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
  frameDoc.document.open();
  frameDoc.document.write('<html><head>'); // add some libraries for the new document
  frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
  frameDoc.document.write(contents);
  frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
  frameDoc.document.close();

  return frame1;
};
```

---

inspired by MDN article:

[`onbeforeprint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeprint)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working Monterey - Safari 16

Answer (score 3):

After some investigation I found a solution.

Safari shows the print warning only if you "Cancel" the print. 
However the reason for the second blank print is that you remove too quickly the content using

```
document.body.removeChild(frame1)
```

If you increase the waiting time from 500ms to 5 secs you give the user the time to close the warning popup and print.

In my case I succesfully tested on Chrome/FF/Edge/Safari this jQuery plugin, increasing also in this library the removal timeout https://github.com/DoersGuild/jQuery.print

Comment: Did you find any other solution ? I mean 5 sec is a huge amount of time ...

Comment: @Laura no, sorry, this solution worked and I didn't check for other solutions. 5 secs is the time that your user has to close the warning, You can adjust it but it's asyncronous with the setTimeout print function, so if it's too low the risk is the print of a blank page.

Comment: Hi @laura and Matteo Conta is there any update on how to fix this issue ? I am having same issue and working on react.

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto this, using the [jQuery Print](https://github.com/DoersGuild/jQuery.print) plugin Matteo Conta mentions above, I was able to implement printing in Safari by doing a print in a new tab, no iframes, popup dialogue, blank prints, or delays.

The issue I was running into, as many people are and have been, was Safari having issues with subsequent prints within iframes, showing that print dialogue, and then a blank print.

Currently we use [printThis JS](https://jasonday.github.io/printThis/#nada) as our printing plugin and had already implemented a 3000ms delay, but this new update Big Sur 14.1 specifically broke that implementation. jQuery Print plugin does not require any delays and may deprecate our use of printThis if we no longer come across anymore issues with Safari updates.

Note: Even with jQuery Print, if you choose to still print within an iframe you'll come across the same printing issues.

Below is a snippet of how I implemented the print based upon the user's browser. Hope this helps anyone still searching for a solution!

```
var currentBrowser;

// Determine user browser
if ( navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1 ) {

  currentBrowser = "Google Chrome";

} else if ( navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1 ) {

  currentBrowser = "Safari";

} else {

  currentBrowser = "Others";
}

// Special Safari Treatment - Print New Window
if( currentBrowser === "Safari" ) {

  /**
   * jQuery Print JS
   *
   * Print receipts in new window with a deffered callback function.
   *
   * globalStyles - Will include style sheets from parent document
   * iframe - Print in a new window, iframe = false
   * deferred - Callback function 
   */
  $("#printDiv").print({
    globalStyles : true,
    iframe : false,
    deferred: $.Deferred().done(function() {

        // Callback
    })
  });

} else {

    // Print iframe normally using printThis JS
    $('#printDiv').printThis();
}
```