# Safari, javascript: wait for print confirmation window

Tags: javascript, safari

I have code like this:

```
hideStuff();
window.print();
showStuff();
```

So, `hideStuff()` hides certain elements on the page so that they do not print, while `showStuff()` restores those hidden elements once the print dialog is closed.

This works on Safari the *first* time I click the print button, but if I then cancel the print dialog, return to the page and click the print button *again*, Safari pops up with a message that reads "This webpage is trying to print. Do you want to print this webpage?" and then if I proceed, the resulting print preview contains all the elements of the page, even those that are supposed to be hidden.

The problem appears to be that the "are you sure" dialog box delays opening the `window.print()`, but it does *allows the javascript to continue.* That is, `showStuff()` runs immediately, not after the print dialog closes.

What can I do to stop execution while that "are you sure" box is open?

Thanks!

Comment: CSS Print Media. Why are you not using it? Set up a print stylesheet that hides what ever you do not want to see.

Comment: I _am_ using print media queries. The above was simplified to illustrate the problem. The before and after functions exist for reasons that are well beyond the scope of this particular question.

Comment: Having the EXACT same issue... happens only in safari.  A solution would be welcome!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [safari not allowing a second window.print()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48524702/safari-not-allowing-a-second-window-print)

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same problem and my investigation showed that `onfocus` event is triggered whenever user hits <kbd>Cancel</kbd> (or <kbd>Esc</kbd> button on a keyboard) to close that confirmation dialog.
Thus, a workaround based on `onfocus` event might look like this:

```
function safariPrint() {
  // Safari 12, macOS
  if (!window.onafterprint) {
    const onAfterPrint = mql => {
      if (!mql.matches) {
        showStuff();

        // printing is finished => unsubscribe to avoid leaks
        if (mediaQueryList.removeEventListener) {
          mediaQueryList.removeEventListener('change', onAfterPrint);
        } else {
          mediaQueryList.removeListener(onAfterPrint);
        }
      }
      window.onfocus = null;
    };

    // a tiny polyfill for a plain onafterprint
    // to handle standard window.print() dialog events
    const mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
    if (mediaQueryList.addEventListener) {
      mediaQueryList.addEventListener('change', onAfterPrint);
    } else {
      mediaQueryList.addListener(onAfterPrint);
    }

    // if a user cancels printing in Safari's print confirmation dialog
    // then we will trigger a cleanup
    window.focus();
    window.onfocus = () => {
      onAfterPrint(mediaQueryList);
    };
  }

  hideStuff();    
  window.print();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working Monterey - Safari 16